# PHP CURL stops script execution in a loop

Tags: php, curl, soap

I have file with some data. I add this data into the database. The amount of this data is more than 3000. While adding this data I use PHP CURL requests in a loop. The request happens when the image exists or updated. Most of them doesn't have an image. In some cases this works as expected, but there are cases where script stops working silently without any errors. I use CURL error reporting function, but returns nothing. Time limit, memory issue and all staffs are done. That isn't reason. The server, which responses my CURL requests uses SOAP. There is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0 );

if ( ! empty( $post_args ) ) {
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $post_args ) );
}

$server_output = curl_exec( $ch );

if ( $server_output === false ) {
  var_dump( curl_error( $ch ) );
  exit;
}

curl_close( $ch );
```

Do you have some idea how to find any solution to debug why CURL requests stops script execution?

Comment: 3000 What? Any units

Comment: 3000 curl requests? The server might not like that very much. Or is it yours?

Comment: Yes, it is mine. Images updates rarely. There is no need to sent 3000 requests every time. Don't worry about it. If you can give me an idea to solve my problem. Thanks